# How can I access my ETC Wallet? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: wallets, ether, ethereum-classic, replay-attack

I would like to do the ETC/ETH split but first I have to access my ETC ethers.

I once created a contract from my main account. How do I get access from my main account to that contract that holds the ether? They are still there on gastracker.io.

So far I tried:

- using geth from Ethereum Classic to rebuild the old blockchain
- copy the key from my main account to `~/.ethereum-classic/keystore`
- start [Ethereum Classic Mist Wallet](https://github.com/ethereumproject/mist/releases/tag/5cbe0c0) 0.8.1 to access the main
  account

Now my questions:

1. There are still some blocks missing. Do I have to sync all blocks to
   access the contract that I made with my main account? Why do the
   last thousend blocks take so long?
2. There are no ether on my main account. Do I need one ether on the
   account to restore my Contract?
3. How exactly do I restore my contract if Mist finally synced? I have
   a hash here from gastracker.io and a password.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. I linked this question to another thread with detailed answers, if anything is unclear, please ask a new question or edit this one to clarify what's missing. Thanks!